# Deleted win8 PBR partition, extending ext to the free space but ubuntu failed to recognize new capacity

Tags: windows, ubuntu

My laptop is an alienware M14x R2 with 128GSSD+750GHDD. Win8 was pre-installed on SSD and ocuppied all of its space. I managed to shrank win8 partition, install ubuntu 12.10 next to it and setup a dual boot.

The problem is that pre-installed win8 leaves a 8 GB PBR partition which is next to ubuntu's ext partition. Since I have built recovery media, I don't need that PBR any more. Then I did as following:

1. I deleted PBR partition(NTFS) in win8 using disk management application
2. Then I selected my ext partition(marked as "RAW" in win8), right click, "extend".

The operation was successful but when I boot into ubuntu I found the capacity of ext partition was not extended. gparted recognized new capacity while ubuntu itself seems to be unaware of the change. What should I do?

Comment: Boot into an Ubuntu LiveUSB, start up GParted and resize it properly. Windows doesn't support Ext4, so I'm not sure how it even let you resize it.

Comment: @Blender thanks. It was displayed as "RAW" in win8. I'll try it.